# If I have two dataframes of which one is a subset of other, how do I remove the common rows completely?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have already looked for this type of question but none of them really answers my question.

Suppose I have two dataframes and the indices of these are NOT consistent. `df2` is a subset of `df1` and I want to remove all the rows in `df1` that are present in `df2`.

I already tried the following but it's not giving me the result I'm looking.

`df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)]`

Unfortunately, I can't share the original data with you however, the number of columns in the two dataframes are 14.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
df1 = 

   month  year  sale
0      1  2012    55
1      4  2014    40
2      7  2013    84
3     10  2014    31
```

```
df2 = 
   month  year  sale
0      1  2012    55
1     10  2014    31
```

and I'm looking for:

```
df = 

   month  year  sale
0      4  2014    40
1      7  2013    84
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a multi-index with all the columns in each dataframe. From that point you have just to drop the indices of the second from the first one:

```
df1.set_index(list(df1.columns)).drop(df2.set_index(list(df2.columns)).index).reset_index()
```

Result with your example data:

```
   month  year  sale
0      4  2014    40
1      7  2013    84
```

Answer (score 1):

Use left join by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and `indicator` parameter, then compare new column for [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df1[df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='left')['_merge'].eq('left_only')]
print (df)
   month  year  sale
1      4  2014    40
2      7  2013    84
```

Comment: I tried this however, after doing this operation my df1 which has 7000 rows and df2 which 2000 rows, I got df with 7 rows. I'm expecting 5000 rows.

Comment: @jukebox - How working `df = df1[df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(), indicator=True, how='left')['_merge'].eq('left_only')]` ?

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is to remove by values, not by index.

Use concatenate and drop:

```py
comp = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10], 'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014], 'sale': [55, 40, 84, 31]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 10], 'year': [2012, 2014], 'sale': [55, 31]})
pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Result:

```
   month  sale  year
1      4    40  2014
2      7    84  2013
```

Comment: I think this should work, but for some reasons when I'm trying this on my original dataframes only 21 rows remain. My original df1 and df2 have 7000 and  2000 rows respectively.

Comment: Could it be you have multiple duplicate values? meaning that `df1` contains multiple duplicates?

Comment: I don't think so. However, let me check. Thanks for pointing out this possibility. :)

Comment: If no duplicates, both solution working nice. But if dupes, this solution  should failed (because e.g. drop duplicates which not matched)

Answer (score 1):

#### can you try below:

```
df1[~df1.isin(df2)]
```